# Shiny Server session time out doesn't work

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app deployed on a Linux server. I want the app to timeout if  there is no activity for a minute. Based on what I read, I added the line `app_idle_timeout` to the `shiny-server.conf` file, but I notice that it doesn't work. Can someone please advice how I can ensure that the session times out after a minute? Note: I do NOT have Shiny Server PRO.

Below is what my `shiny-server.conf` looks like:

```
Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;
 
  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    app_idle_timeout 60;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;

  }
}
~
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can configure your `idle` time within the `shiny` app like so using some JS, here the app will timeout after 5 seconds.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

inactivity <- "function idleTimer() {
  var t = setTimeout(logout, 5000);
  window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
  window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
  window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
  window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
  window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

  function logout() {
    window.close();  //close the window
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(logout, 5000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
  }
}
idleTimer();"


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(inactivity),    
  leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })

})
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: A close solution that works since 09/2018. `library(shiny);ui <- fluidPage( textOutput("keepAlive"), titlePanel("Hello !"), HTML( " <script> var Msg = false;var interv;var n = 0;var delay_ms = 60 * 1000;var duration_bef = 240; $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {interv = setInterval(function() {if (n < duration_bef) {if (n == duration_bef - 2 && !(Msg)) {alert('Refresh before timeout '); Msg = true;}Shiny.onInputChange('Occur', n++);}}, delay_ms) }); $(document).on('shiny:disconnected', function(event) {clearInterval(interv) }); </script>" ) )` 1/2

Comment: `server <- function(input, output) { output$keepAlive <- renderText({duration_bef<- 240; req(input$Occur); if (input$Occur<duration_bef) { paste(input$Occur, " min ") } else {paste("Make F5 (<",duration_bef,"min)")}})};shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server);` 2/2. From https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015932932-Increasing-the-timeout-for-Shiny-Server

Comment: How does this work when you want the opposite...so that the app never tiimes out?

Comment: BY default your app will look for the config file within the shinyserver, you can set those as per https://docs.posit.co/shiny-server/#application-timeouts

Answer (score 21):

@PorkChop, thanks for your very useful answer!

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a slightly modified version of @PorkChop's code which doesen't close the browser tab, but instead only closes the session and leaves a message for the user:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

timeoutSeconds <- 5

inactivity <- sprintf("function idleTimer() {
var t = setTimeout(logout, %s);
window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

function logout() {
Shiny.setInputValue('timeOut', '%ss')
}

function resetTimer() {
clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(logout, %s);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
}
}
idleTimer();", timeoutSeconds*1000, timeoutSeconds, timeoutSeconds*1000)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(inactivity),    
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  
  observeEvent(input$timeOut, { 
    print(paste0("Session (", session$token, ") timed out at: ", Sys.time()))
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Timeout",
      paste("Session timeout due to", input$timeOut, "inactivity -", Sys.time()),
      footer = NULL
    ))
    session$close()
  })
  
  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })
  
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image: result]

[This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) was very helpful to get here.

Comment: If the app is split into ui.R and server.R files, can this code go in the server.R file?

Comment: If you want to replicate it 1:1 you can put the variables`timeoutSeconds` and `inactivity` in a file called global.R in the same folder as ui.R and server.R.

Comment: @ismirsehregal this is a great answer, and worked for me. I was able to end sessions on the open source server with this. rookieJoe I would consider marking this as your accepted answer.

Comment: This is great! It closes the individual session but leaves the app running. How would you close the app when the last session is closed?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/trestletech/9926129) you can find an example on how to count active sessions. In the `onSessionEnded` callback you can check if the number of sessions = 0 and run `stopApp()`.

Comment: How does this work when you want the opposite...so that the app never times out? –

Answer (score 2):

The session timeout feature isn't available on the open source shiny server. It comes only as part of the pro version.

Comment: I have added the example to bypass that