# How to define time-out option for Shiny app

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app hosted in AWS. Now I want to define a Time-out option for my App, say as 5 min. Means, if a user is not active over the shiny app for more than 5 min then my App should get disconnected from the server.

Any idea which parameter to look for in the Shiny server config page?

Answer (score 2):

Since my answer havent been accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839543/shiny-server-session-time-out-doesnt-work) I will post it here. not that i used a small bit of `JS` to detect inactivity. You dont need the `leaflet` library as it is only a demo. The app will close the window after 5 secs

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

inactivity <- "function idleTimer() {
  var t = setTimeout(logout, 5000);
  window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
  window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
  window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
  window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
  window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

  function logout() {
    window.close();  //close the window
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(logout, 5000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
  }
}
idleTimer();"


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(inactivity),    
  leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })

})
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: This is working with local deployment, but not in e.g. AWS

Comment: it is working on AWS as I have it in my apps which are on amazon. Note that I've only tested it using Google Chrome

Comment: @SimonWoodward only the pro version has the timeout feature

Comment: Cool good to know. I am using a corporate server so I'm guessing it is pro.