# shiny server running, apps disconnected from the server

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I had an issue with an app or all apps that are running locally with shiny server , I did much troubleshooting but always getting "Disconnected from the server.
Reload"

all logs are from 05 january , I still dont know what is the real reason behind this , any expert who can assist ?

Thanks

restarting , reloading shiny server

checking logs but nothing came up

Comment: The logs will reset once the app is no longer running, so open the logs during the crash, most likely there is a R bug in there somewhere

Comment: I cant find out, not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

By default, shiny server will go to sleep and kill the associated R process if there is no activity. You can stop this behavior by setting:

```
location / {
    app_idle_timeout 0;
}
```

In `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`

More details in the [shiny server docs](https://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/os/latest/#application-timeouts) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417101/how-can-i-prevent-my-shiny-app-from-disconnecting-in-a-open-source-shiny-server#:%7E:text=You%20can%20disable%20application%20idle,your%20Shiny%20Server%20config%20file.)