# ShinyManager authentication screen does not time out

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

sorry to be asking this question again, but I really need this problem solved (about to reach my max data limit on shinyapps.io). Here is the link to my previous question [Previous Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001580/login-screen-for-my-shiny-app-does-not-time-out)
Here is the link to my demo app. [Demo App Hosted On ShinyApps.io](https://financialtrading.shinyapps.io/shiny/) You will notice the app does not time out. For example here is my logs for this app just for today. [image]

I have tried everything that was recommended to me from my last question as well as including the `timeOut` parameter in the `shinymanager::secure_server()` function.

What seems to be the problem is, shinyapps.io puts a timer for inactivity on the UI. Once the UI is inactive it then starts a timeout on the `R` process. However, in our case the UI does not start up until authentication. This means our server keeps running.

Something like a set timeout (`setTimeout()`) would be a great alternative. For example, if the user does not authenticate within 5 minutes, time out. I initially tried a while loop, but it did not turn out as planned.

I am looking for a way to time out the server if there is no activity. 
Here is a toy example of what my code looks like.
Lastly, here is a link to the shinymanager package on github. [shinymanager](https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager)

Ui.R

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
   #My UI page and functions
 )
shinymanager::secure_app(ui)
```

Server.R

```
function(input, output, session){
 auth = secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(df)) #df is my client database

 observeEvent(auth$user,{
    #server functions. This only gets run once the user authenticates
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to start a new question instead of continuing your old question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This app will timeout after 120 seconds, if no credentials are entered

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

inactivity <- "function idleTimer() {
var t = setTimeout(logout, 120000);
window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

function logout() {
window.close();  //close the window
}

function resetTimer() {
clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(logout, 120000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
}
}
idleTimer();"


# data.frame with credentials info
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("1", "fanny", "victor", "benoit"),
  password = c("1", "azerty", "12345", "azerty"),
  # comment = c("alsace", "auvergne", "bretagne"), %>% 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- secure_app(head_auth = tags$script(inactivity),
                 fluidPage(
                   # classic app
                   headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
                     selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                                 selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
                     numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                                  min = 1, max = 9)
                   ),
                   mainPanel(
                     plotOutput('plot1'),
                     verbatimTextOutput("res_auth")
                   )

                 ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  result_auth <- secure_server(check_credentials = 
                                 check_credentials(credentials))

  output$res_auth <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(result_auth)
  })

  # classic app
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: OMG! Pork Chop Thank You!! This saved my ass. It works great! Would you mind breaking this down 1 step further? I do not understand the tags$script(inactivity) call in the UI. Why are we not calling this in the server. I thought my UI does not get run until someone authenticates. Thanks

Comment: The `secure_app` takes in some arguments in the `...` so You can put some the `js` code in there. Because this package uses modules under the hood it works are a bit different and renders a different ui to start with.