# set Shiny (Open Source edition) session timeout

Tags: r, shiny

I found this trick to set a session timeout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53207050/3720258.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work anymore, and I have an API + Dashboard to explore official Covid Data in my country (https://coronavirus.mat.uc.cl/, https://coronavirus-api.mat.uc.cl/).

So far, I applied a CRON job in the meanwhile to restart shiny-server, at the expense that it closes active sessions. See how the memory is releases after closing all those inactive sessions:

[image]

How can I enforce that sessions  that remain inactive for more than T seconds are automatically disconnected?